Differential operator on $L^p\left(0, 1\right)$
Let $X = L^p\left(0, 1\right)$, with $p \in [1, \infty)$ and $Y = \{f \in AC([0, 1]); f' \in X\}$ (consider $Y$ as a subspace of $X$.
Define operators $T_j$ (all of them by the same formula $T_j(f) = f'$
$D(T_1) = Y, D(T_2) = \{f\in Y; f(0) = 0\}, D(T_3) = \{f\in Y; f(1) = 0\}, D(T_4) = \{f\in Y, f(0) = f(1) = 0\}$,
$D(T_5) = \{f\in Y; f(0) = f(1)\}, D(T_6) = \{f\in Y; f(0) = -f(1)\}$.
Show that all those operators are densely defined and closed.
For the densely defined part, it's easy to see that $T_4 \subset T_3, T_2, T_5, T_6(?) \subset T_1$. Since $D(T_4)$ contains $\mathcal{D}(0, 1)$ (space of test functions) they are all densely defined. I am not entirely sure about $T_6$. So that would be for the densely defined.
I am stuck at the closed part. Any help is appreciated, thanks :)

What's the problem with $T_6$? If $f(0) = f(1) = 0$, then surely $f(0) = -f(1)$?

To show that $T_i$ are closed, you can use that this is equivalent to saying: for a sequence $(f_n)\in D(T_i)$ with $f_n\rightarrow f\in X$ and $T_i f_n=f_n'\rightarrow g\in X$ we have $f\in D(T_i)$ and $f'=g$. We will use this.
For $i\in\{1,\dots,6\}$ take such a sequence $(f_n)_n\subset D(T_i)$.
To argue that $f\in D(T_i)$, note that the graph norm is $\left\lVert\cdot\right\rVert_{D(T_i)}=\left\lVert\cdot\right\rVert_{\infty}+\left\lVert T_i\cdot\right\rVert_\infty$ and this gives us in this case that the convergence of $f_n$ to $f$ and the convergence of $f_n'$ to $g$ are uniform and this together preserves the differentiability, i.e. $f$ is differentiable. So $f'\in X$ and thus $f\in Y$. The uniform convergence also implies pointwise convergence and this is why for all domains $D(T_i)$ these conditions like $f(0)=0$ etc. are preserved. Hence $f\in D(T_i)$ for $i=1,\dots,6$.
Furthermore $\left\lVert f'-g \right\rVert_X\leqslant \left\lVert f'-f_n' \right\rVert+\left\lVert f_n'-g \right\rVert$ for which the righthand side can now be made as small as possible, i.e. if we let $\varepsilon>0$ then there is an $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n>N$ we have $\left\lVert f'-g \right\rVert_X<\varepsilon$. Since $\varepsilon$ was arbitrary we have $f'=g$.
The equivalence stated initially now implies that your $T_i$ are all closed.

The norm to consider for closedness for any operator $T : D(T) \subset X \to X$ is $f \mapsto |f|_X + |T(f)|_X$, or its sibling $(|f|_X^2 + |T(f)|_X^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ (you'd take the latter for Hilbert spaces), due to the fact that closedness of the operator is equivalent to completeness of the domain for said norm. You do have uniform convergence not because it's the norm on $Y$ but because convergence in the norm of $Y$ implies uniform convergence in our case.

The rest should be fine however (+1).

[...] uniform convergence preserves the differentiability so $f'\in X$ and thus $f\in Y$.
Why is this true? I know it preserves continuity. Maybe it's something trivial but I don't really see it.

@L731289 I have edited my answer taking also the comment of Bruno into account. I forgot to mention that the derivatives converge uniformly, this is also needed for $f'\in X$ to hold.

Lisa, $|\cdot|_\infty$ shouldn't be involved in your graph norm, everything happens in $L^p$... The derivatives converging in the $L^p$ norm gives uniform convergence for the $f_n$s, which lets you transfer the "pointwise" properties of the $f_n$s like $f(0) = 0$ and so on, but you still only have $L^p$ convergence for the derivatives. Still, $L^p$ convergence is all you need for weak derivatives. As for you @L731289, $Y$ is a Sobolev space, so you should be able to find a proof of its completeness somewhere, and then see the other domains as closed subspaces of $Y$ for their completeness.

@BrunoB You are completely right. I looked over the definitions too quickly, saw $AC$ and had the supnorm in mind... Thank you for your corrections however. I do appreciate it.
